# Show all uncovered lines of code via ncrunch

Tags: ncrunch

Ncrunch shows lines of code, which are not covered by tests as black bubbles...

Is there a possibility to show all lines of code which are not covered by tests? (Something like a dotCover code inspection report)

Thanks in advance

Comment: thats what i figured :-(

Comment: you should probably request that feature on the ncrunch forum though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ncrunch supports this feature from version 1.39b. There is a metrics button where you can have an aggregated overview of coverage (solution, project, file). Neat feature.

Comment: This is great. It needs to be polished up a bit, but it's 80% of the way there.